# How to install PostGIS on Oracle Linux 6.4 x64?

Tags: linux, postgresql, postgis, rhel

I am reading the following guide http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/329-An-almost-idiots-guide-to-install-PostgreSQL-9.3,-PostGIS-2.1-and-pgRouting-with-Yum.html (this link is from http://postgis.net/install). The command `yum install postgis2_93` gives the following errors:

```
Error: Package: gdal-libs-1.9.2-6.rhel6.x86_64 (pgdg93)
           Requires: libhdf5.so.6()(64bit)
Error: Package: gdal-libs-1.9.2-6.rhel6.x86_64 (pgdg93)
           Requires: libdapserver.so.7()(64bit)
Error: Package: gdal-libs-1.9.2-6.rhel6.x86_64 (pgdg93)
           Requires: libCharLS.so.1()(64bit)
Error: Package: postgis2_93-2.1.3-1.rhel6.x86_64 (pgdg93)
           Requires: libjson.so.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: gdal-libs-1.9.2-6.rhel6.x86_64 (pgdg93)
           Requires: libgta.so.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: gdal-libs-1.9.2-6.rhel6.x86_64 (pgdg93)
           Requires: libspatialite.so.2()(64bit)
Error: Package: gdal-libs-1.9.2-6.rhel6.x86_64 (pgdg93)
           Requires: libcfitsio.so.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: postgis2_93-2.1.3-1.rhel6.x86_64 (pgdg93)
           Requires: json-c
Error: Package: postgis2_93-2.1.3-1.rhel6.x86_64 (pgdg93)
           Requires: hdf5
Error: Package: armadillo-4.300.0-1.rhel6.x86_64 (pgdg93)
           Requires: libhdf5.so.6()(64bit)
Error: Package: gdal-libs-1.9.2-6.rhel6.x86_64 (pgdg93)
           Requires: libnetcdf.so.6()(64bit)
Error: Package: gdal-libs-1.9.2-6.rhel6.x86_64 (pgdg93)
           Requires: libdapclient.so.3()(64bit)
Error: Package: armadillo-4.300.0-1.rhel6.x86_64 (pgdg93)
           Requires: libarpack.so.2()(64bit)
Error: Package: gdal-libs-1.9.2-6.rhel6.x86_64 (pgdg93)
           Requires: libfreexl.so.1()(64bit)
Error: Package: gdal-libs-1.9.2-6.rhel6.x86_64 (pgdg93)
           Requires: libdap.so.11()(64bit)
```

They were expected. Then I do the following (it's according to the guide):

```
sudo rpm -ivh http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
```

and `yum install postgis2_93` gives the following:

```
http://mirror.logol.ru/epel/6/x86_64/repodata/9fdd4609f219b3ec5cfa5408ab03b84b2bce97ab6de268b890577ee86b998618-primary.sqlite.bz2: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.
http://mirror.awanti.com/epel/6/x86_64/repodata/9fdd4609f219b3ec5cfa5408ab03b84b2bce97ab6de268b890577ee86b998618-primary.sqlite.bz2: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.
http://ftp.fi.muni.cz/pub/linux/fedora/epel/6/x86_64/repodata/9fdd4609f219b3ec5cfa5408ab03b84b2bce97ab6de268b890577ee86b998618-primary.sqlite.bz2: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.
http://ftp.linux.cz/pub/linux/fedora/epel/6/x86_64/repodata/9fdd4609f219b3ec5cfa5408ab03b84b2bce97ab6de268b890577ee86b998618-primary.sqlite.bz2: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.
http://centos.kiewel-online.ch/epel/6/x86_64/repodata/9fdd4609f219b3ec5cfa5408ab03b84b2bce97ab6de268b890577ee86b998618-primary.sqlite.bz2: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.
http://ftp.uni-kl.de/pub/linux/fedora-epel/6/x86_64/repodata/9fdd4609f219b3ec5cfa5408ab03b84b2bce97ab6de268b890577ee86b998618-primary.sqlite.bz2: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.
http://mirror.switch.ch/ftp/mirror/epel/6/x86_64/repodata/9fdd4609f219b3ec5cfa5408ab03b84b2bce97ab6de268b890577ee86b998618-primary.sqlite.bz2: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.
http://www.mirrorservice.org/sites/dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/repodata/9fdd4609f219b3ec5cfa5408ab03b84b2bce97ab6de268b890577ee86b998618-primary.sqlite.bz2: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.
...
```

`yum clean all` and `yum clean metadata` don't solve the problem. I also tried to use EPEL 7.1, but I got the same errors. Where can I get these packages?

Comment: Are you using the PostgreSQL RPMs from http://yum.postgresql.org/ or elsewhere?

Comment: @CraigRinger Yes, I use RPMs from yum.postgresql.org. I have installed it like it is written in that instruction: `rpm -ivh http://yum.postgresql.org/9.3/redhat/rhel-6-x86_64/pgdg-oraclelinux93-9.3-1.noarch.rpm && yum install postgresql93 postgresql93-server postgresql93-libs postgresql93-contrib postgresql93-devel` It has passed with no errors.

Comment: So your issue is that you can't fetch package-lists from EPEL. Proxy/firewall issues? (BTW, I've close-voted this as off topic for Stack Overflow).

Comment: @CraigRinger I use neither proxy nor firewall. Therefore I can't understand where the problem is.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Switch to baseurl in /etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo:

```
baseurl=http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/$basearch
#mirrorlist=https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=epel-6&arch=$basearch
```

The fix will propagate to the mirrors within the next couple of hours.

Be sure to switch to mirrorlist again later on, so that we don't all hammer the hosts assigned to download.fedoraproject.org

Answer (score 0):

It works for me.

```sh
yum install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
```

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/598051/522973